# is there a way to run more then one IntentService at ones?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service, intentservice

I think I've got the point of IntentService class. it handles a queue which prevents too or more instances of the service been executed together.

I've found it useful,  but what if I have too derived classes from IntentService which have different purpose, and I want both of them running together without waiting to each other?

It was great if there is any flag or attribute I can set, that will say something like: "allow to too or more diffrent derived class of intent service to run each one on his own queue"

is there any way doing that?

I know about all the other alternatives such as "regular" service, AsyncTesk, manually manage threads,  so please don't suggest me consider using them instead. I know their advantages and limitations.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing preventing two `IntentService`s from executing together.

As an example, given a service, `ServiceA`

```
public class ServiceA extends IntentService {
   ...
}
```

and a subclass of `ServiceA` aptly named `ServiceB`

```
public class ServiceB extends ServiceA {
}
```

`ServiceB` will **not** share an executor/queue (or *anything* else for that matter) with `ServiceA`, i.e. both can execute at the same time. You can easily test this by putting a loop in `ServiceA`, e.g.

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName() + " says hello");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

and then calling

```
startService(new Intent(this, ServiceA.class));
startService(new Intent(this, ServiceB.class));
```

from your `Activity`. They will both be running at the same time.

Comment: thanks for your good answer, but are you sure about that? because I've created my own test which make me come to diffrent conclusion (it's possible I've made bad assumption...)

Comment: You can look at the source code for [IntentService.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java) at github - it creates a handler thread for each instance of the class & shares nothing between instances, i.e. a subclass will execute whatever is in its `onHandleIntent` independently of the parent class.